# How hot would days get if it were always the solstice in the northern hemisphere?

Tags: geophysics, climate

Imagine the Earth's axis of rotation were to precess in synch with the orbit of earth around the sun so the north pole always pointed towards the sun (same current axial tilt of about 23 degrees).  Inside the arctic circle it would always be day light.  Between the tropics and the arctic circle daylight hours would vary from slightly greater than 12 hours to much greater than 12 hours.

This would obviously wreak havoc on jet streams and thermohaline currents, but eventually things would stabilize and you'd reach a max temperature (ish) relative to latitude.

How scorchingly hot would the high arctic get and what would more temperate zones like 35 and 45 degrees latitude max out at for daily highs?